# Restrict bower components access in Apache

Tags: apache

I am using Apache to host a web application, which has the following [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyBBZ.png). The application is working fine.

But when "http://localhost/library/bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/" URL is used, the calendar page appears just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxZBs.png).

Please suggest any way to restrict the access of bower components from the browser.